# Why doesn't BigQuery allow my regex that works in Postgres?

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I'm running the following query against a Postgres DB:

```
SUBSTRING(my_col, '[0-9\-]+') AS extracted_string
```

Which works fine and extracts the sequence I want, but when I run the equivalent BigQuery query:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(my_col, '[0-9\-]+') AS extracted_string
```

It throws an exception saying:

`Syntax error: Illegal escape sequence: \\-`

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify that your regex strings are in fact regex strings and should be treated differently in BigQuery.

The fix is to place the `r` character in front of your regex string like so:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(my_col, r'[0-9\-]+') AS extracted_string
```